# Excel - Return multiple matching values from a column matching two variables, horizontally in one row

Tags: excel, indexing, match, lookup

I have this table:

```
|   | A       | B      | C |
|---|---------|--------|---|
| 1 |         |        |   |
| 2 | Oranges | Red    | 1 |
| 3 | Apples  | Yellow | 2 |
| 4 | Grapes  | Orange | 3 |
| 5 | Oranges | Orange | 4 |
| 6 | Apples  | Red    | 5 |
| 7 | Grapes  | Green  | 6 |
| 8 | Apples  | Green  | 7 |
```

I want to check for matching values in Column A like **Apples,Yellow** , **Apples,Green**, etc... and return all the corresponding values from `Column B` in one row:

I tried to nest AND into IF but didn't work out as it wasn't returning any values at all.

```
|    | A       | B           | C | D | E |
|----|---------|-------------|---|---|---|
| 11 | Apples  | Green       | 1 |   |   |
| 12 | Oranges | YellowGreen | 2 |   |   |
```

#### My code:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$8, SMALL(IF($A$11=$A$2:$A$8, ROW($A$2:$A$8)-ROW($A$2)+1), COLUMN(A1)))
```

How do I get this formula to look at two variables to match?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using an array formula, wouldn't concatenating work?

```
{=INDEX($C$2:$C$8, SMALL(IF($A11&" "&$B11=$A$2:$A$8&" "&$B$2:$B$8, ROW($A$2:$A$8)-ROW($A$2)+1), COLUMN(A1)))}
```

Comment: What would you think about nesting AND into the IF logical test, would there be a chance to get it working?

Comment: would it be possible for array to match one of the variables and the other part to be bigger then zero? could it have = and > in the same IF?